# how to send data to server from iphone application

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode

I am sending data from iphone application to server using php but data is not inserted in the data base when i post the data in return it just sents the [] in echo.

My iPhone Code

```
    -(void)submitSurveyAnswers{


     NSString*survey_question_response_id="1";
     NSString*survey_id=@"1";
     NSString *question_id =@"1";
     NSString *survey_response_answer_id =@"1";
     NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"survey_question_response_id=%@&survey_id=%@&question_id=%@&survey_response_answer_id=%@",survey_question_response_id,survey_id,question_id,survey_response_answer_id];
     NSLog(post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver-solutions.com/app/surveyAnswer.php?"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
   NSError *error;
   NSURLResponse *response;
   NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

  NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@",data);
  }
```

Here is the my php code

```
    <?php
    $host = ""; 
    $user = ""; 
    $pass = ""; 
    $database = ""; 

    $linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 

    mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 

    $survey_question_response_id=$_POST['survey_question_response_id'];
    $survey_id=$_POST['survey_id'];
    $question_id=$_POST['question_id'];
    $survey_response_answer_id=$_POST['survey_response_answer_id'];
    echo($survey_question_response_id);

    $query=("INSERT INTO survey_question_responses
```

(survey_question_response_id,survey_id,question_id,survey_response_answer_id)

```
    VALUES ('$survey_question_response_id', '$survey_id','$question_id','$survey_response_answer_id')");

     mysql_query($query,$con);
     printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
     echo($survey_id)
     ?>
```

Comment: can you check if you are getting query string values in php. Just echo them

Comment: @DimplePanchal can you tell me how to check the querry string

Comment: the fields in the data base all are integer

Comment: if values are int then you cant keep quotes   `VALUES ('$survey_question_response_id', '$survey_id','$question_id','$survey_response_answer_id')");`

Comment: it is giving error like this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/surveyResponse.php on line 30

Comment: U need `;` there in echo statement

Comment: $query=("INSERT INTO survey_question_responses (survey_question_response_id,survey_id,question_id,survey_response_answer_id)
VALUES ('$survey_question_response_id', '$survey_id','$question_id','$survey_response_answer_id')");

Comment: sorry dimple there was data base connection it is ok now it showing following result

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO person (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

Comment: 11
Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/surveyResponse.php on line 37
Records inserted: -1 1

Comment: but it showing as i told 11 warnig mysqlquery supplied arguement is not a valid Mysql link resource

Comment: U need these  `$host = ""; 
    $user = ""; 
    $pass = ""; 
    $database = "";`

Comment: yes i have given these but i think problem is in querry it is showing error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']' in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/surveyResponse.php on line 36

Comment: below is the query which is showing error

Comment: $query="INSERT INTO survey_question_responses (survey_question_response_id,survey_id,question_id,survey_response_answer_id)
VALUES ('$_POST[survey_question_response_id]', '$_POST[survey_id]','$_POST[question_id]','$_POST[survey_response_answer_id'])";

Comment: n_id]','$_POST[survey_response_answer_id'])"; Here is the issue

Comment: what is the issue over here can you tell me please

Comment: It should be n_id]','$_POST[survey_response_answer_id]')";

Comment: yes i have done like this i also find this but again showing error

Comment: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/surveyResponse.php on line 42
Records inserted: -1 1

Comment: @DimplePanchal again showing the above error in querry

Comment: conn means connection :)

Comment: Why don't you use [ASIHTTPRequest][1] ?? It saves you a lot of time and coding.


  [1]: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a full example on Github to dynamically create forms and submit them to a POST server. You may be able to use it depending upon how complex your forms are. Each form is described in a plist and is very dynamic.

If it is missing support for any desired form type (checkboxes, drop-down, etc.), let me know and I'd be happy to add them. (I only needed text-based input in my forms so far, but if there is a demand, I'd like to expand it to more complex items too!)

(A PHP file is also included to catch the response.)

https://github.com/mikecheckDev/MDContactForm